# How to iterate over objects in array and sum a property without iterating?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add up all `duration` values of an object array without iteration?

```
const data = [
  {
    duration: 10
    any: 'other fields'
  },
  {
    duration: 20
    any: 'other fields'
  }
]
```

Result should be '30'.

```
let result = 0
data.forEach(d => {
  result = result + d.duration
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: no, it is not possible to iterate an array without iteration - by the way, I recommend using reduce ... `let result = data.reduce((r, d) => r + d.duration, 0);`

Comment: It's not possible. An efficient way to do this would be to use reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: I believe quantum computers are capable of solving this problem without iterating.

Comment: While it is an unfeasible notion to attempt to iterate without using iteration, one may use recursion instead of iteration to extract the indicated object property value from each of the array's objects and total those values.  In fact, "...iteration is just a special case of recursion (tail recursion)" (see: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~shidi/cs61a/wiki/Iteration_vs._recursion). See example code at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxwdpR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I does not work without some iteration, to get a sum of a specified property.

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a callback and a start value of zero.

```js
const data = [{ duration: 10, any: 'other fields' }, { duration: 20, any: 'other fields' }];
let result = data.reduce((r, d) => r + d.duration, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't accomplish this without iteration.
You can use [array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) , which uses iteration.

```js
const data = [
  {
    duration: 10,
    any: 'other fields'
  },
  {
    duration: 20,
    any: 'other fields'
  }
];

var result = data.reduce(
  (sum, obj) => sum + obj['duration'] 
  ,0
);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```